# OpenSSL 1.0.1j - "POODLE" vulnerability fix (upgrade) on RHEL 6.5

Tags: linux, openssl, poodle

I've got a problem when I upgraded my OpenSSL on RHEL 6.5. The OpenSSL is missing the library `libcrypto.so.10`. Instead the `openssl 1.0.1j` created lib is `libcrypto.so.1.0.0`. I've made a soft link, but it still does not work for other packages using `libcrypto.so.10`.

Does anyone have experience on this problem?

**Explanation (addendum/edit):** this is required info since many will be looking to use the 1.0.1j version directly from the OpenSSL package to escape the latest (2014.10.15) "POODLE" vulnerability in OpenSSL. If you get the tar.gz file from openssl.org at this time, you should not have a problem. There previously was a problem for a short time and that publication may still exist on other sites, so avoid taking down the file other than at openssl.org:
[openssl downloads](https://www.openssl.org/source/).

Please read through the SSL3 warning in the @jvp answer regarding RPM's since the updates do not completely solve server problems that arise when servers permit such connections. a discussion of this additional vulnerability can be found at:
[ncas division of us-cert.gov](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA14-290A)

See the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162623/7453) regarding using Red Hat based RPM's for EL6 and EL7.

Look to your `/usr/lib` directory for 32-bit and `/usr/lib64` for 64 bit and the layout should be as follows:

- libcrypto.a
- libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.0.1j
- libcrypto.so.10 -> libcrypto.so.1.0.1j
- libcrypto.so.1.0.1j
- .libcrypto.so.1.0.1j.hmac
- .libcrypto.so.10.hmac -> .libcrypto.so.1.0.1j.hmaclibssl.a
- libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.1j
- libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.1j
- libssl.so.1.0.1j
- .libssl.so.1.0.1j.hmac
- .libssl.so.10.hmac -> .libssl.so.1.0.1j.hmac

There are also the lib sub-directories `openssl` and `package`, but these have never been a problem.

Comment: By which means did you update OpenSSL? An official update from RHEL? A third party RPM? By doing 'make install??

Comment: Very likely it should be `libcrypto.so.1`, not `libcrypto.so.10`.

Answer (score 2):

The RPM's are out for RHEL [6|7] and siblings (i.e., CentOS et al.) and available via   yum  at most repositories.

Please note that these RPM's address a portion of the "POODLE" vulnerabilities per:

- CVE-2014-3567,
- CVE-2014-3566, and
- CVE-2014-3513

SEE:
[cert.gov](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/current-activity/2014/10/16/OpenSSL-Patches-Four-Vulnerabilities)

The security update *does not* address some specific SSLv3 problems, so those with servers being updated must remove any possibility of clients connecting using this protocol and -- specifically -- CBC methods.

Removing SSL3 from server config's is really easy to do by:

#### NGINX/TENGINE:

- add/replace `ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;` in the `http`
  config section and
- make certain that the 'ssl_protocols' directive is
  not over-ridden in any server sections.

If you find any server directives, just remove them and let 'HTTP' govern ... as it should anyway.

#### APACHE:

- add/replace `SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3` in the global SSL configuration section and
- as with Nginx, check your vhosts.

As with previous OpenSSL snafus, instead of issuing new RPM numbers to match the updated OpenSSL version number (1.0.1j), the `.rpm` has a patch back-ported to the last extent `.rpm` of the distro; which is 1.0.1e (for RHEL-based distros) and is fully versioned — as of this moment — as `1.0.1e-30.[variable by specific machine version]`.

So, taking CentOS 6 64-bit as an example, the `.rpm` you will get is `openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_5.2.x86_64.rpm`.

As with any OpenSSL update, anything that relies upon OpenSSL such as web servers, VPN's, and the like must be restarted on the server before the update will come into play.

Comment: As @jvp said, `openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_5.2` on CentOS 6.5 adds support for `TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV` So a simple `yum update openssl` should be sufficient in applying the patch on CentOS. Source: http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2014-October/020697.html - Granted the updated was probably not applicable around the time of the original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1j.tar.gz
tar -xvf openssl-1.0.1j.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1j
./config --prefix=/usr no-threads shared
make
make test
make install

openssl version
```

Comment: That's not great advice IMO, better to stick to vendor-provided packages. Also, please put some explanation about what this does and why it will fix hungwar's problem.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution manual for the standard configuration of apache or DirectAdmin with Apache or Litespeed - Centos 6+,7

Still no updates are available on the CentOS for fix openssl

Comment: A fix for what OpenSSL issue?

Comment: The OpenSSL `1.0.1j`, `1.0.0o`, and `0.9.8zc` packages add support for `TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV` This allows applications to block the ability for a MITM attacker to force a protocol downgrade. eg POODLE